# How many pixels do items in QComboBox need?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to know how many pixels need this items in QComboBox:

[image: Picture]

1. red - checkbox
2. green - distance between end of checkbox and beggining of the text
3. blue - distance between end of border and beggining of the checkbox

In doc of QStyle I find two methods:

1. subElementRect()
2. pixelMetric()
   I think I have to use them, but I don't know, which args I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the style.

`QCommonStyle` for example draws the ComboBox's label like [this](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp.html#2199):

```
if (const QStyleOptionComboBox *cb = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionComboBox *>(opt)) {
    QRect editRect = proxy()->subControlRect(CC_ComboBox, cb, SC_ComboBoxEditField, widget);
    p->save();
    p->setClipRect(editRect);
    if (!cb->currentIcon.isNull()) {
        QIcon::Mode mode = cb->state & State_Enabled ? QIcon::Normal
                                                     : QIcon::Disabled;
        QPixmap pixmap = cb->currentIcon.pixmap(qt_getWindow(widget), cb->iconSize, mode);
        QRect iconRect(editRect);
        iconRect.setWidth(cb->iconSize.width() + 4);
        iconRect = alignedRect(cb->direction,
                               Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter,
                               iconRect.size(), editRect);
        if (cb->editable)
            p->fillRect(iconRect, opt->palette.brush(QPalette::Base));
        proxy()->drawItemPixmap(p, iconRect, Qt::AlignCenter, pixmap);
        if (cb->direction == Qt::RightToLeft)
            editRect.translate(-4 - cb->iconSize.width(), 0);
        else
            editRect.translate(cb->iconSize.width() + 4, 0);
    }
    if (!cb->currentText.isEmpty() && !cb->editable) {
        proxy()->drawItemText(p, editRect.adjusted(1, 0, -1, 0),
                     visualAlignment(cb->direction, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter),
                     cb->palette, cb->state & State_Enabled, cb->currentText);
    }
    p->restore();
}
```

This means, that the actual size of the icon's rectangle can be determined by subclassing `QComboBox` (to access its protected `initStyleOption` method) and creating a new public `getIconRect` method in the following way:

```
QRect ComboBox::getIconRect()
{
    QStyleOptionComboBox opt;
    initStyleOption(&opt);

    QRect rect(style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &opt, QStyle::SC_ComboBoxEditField));

    rect.setWidth(opt.iconSize.width() + 4);

    return rect;
}
```

Then in `MainWindow` for example create a `ComboBox` and call its `getIconSize` method like this:

```
auto *cmbBox = new ComboBox(this);

qDebug() << cmbBox->getIconRect();
```

For me, on Windows 10, this gives:

> QRect(3,3 20x14)

There could be other ways, but if you insist on using a method similar to `QStyle::subControlRect`, those are the correct arguments;

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much user6528273! I have two other questions: 1) Why we add this +4? I see that number is in QCommonStyle code, but I thought that if I use subControlRect I will have proper width. 2) Which elements I have to search in QStyle doc? I don't need Icon, but this 3 things from first post.

Comment: @nowaczek, __Why we add this +4?__ I am afraid you have to ask whoever wrote `QCommonStyle`. 
:) __I don't need Icon, but this 3 things from first post__ I think `blue` is `3` (the `x`-offset in the result), `red` is the icon - `16` (see also [`QComboBox::iconSize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#iconSize-prop)), and `green` is `4`, probably that is this +4 for.

Comment: @nowaczek spoko ;)